# Problem with keeping records in RecyclerView when rotating the screen

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, android-livedata

I am developing an Android application on my own, applying the knowledge learned in the courses "Android Basics in Kotlin", "Modern Android app architecture", "Advanced Android in Kotlin" and "Accessibility".
The app loads product and category data from the Firebase Realtime Database and displays it in different RecyclerViews, depending on the selected category.

My problem arises when rotating the screen, since the records in the RecyclerView are lost. I have tried to implement LiveData, ViewBinding, MVVM and Repository, but I can't find the solution.

I would like to request your help to understand and correct this problem. I want to continue learning and improve my skills in developing Android applications with Kotlin.

I appreciate any suggestions or advice you can offer me.

Thank you very much in advance.

```
class ProductListFragment : Fragment(), ProductItemClickListener, ProductTypeItemClickListener {

    enum class SortOrder {
        ASC,
        DESC
    }

    private var _binding: FragmentProductListBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    // Product Types
    private lateinit var rvProductTypes: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var productTypeAdapter: ProductCategoryAdapter

    // Products
    private lateinit var rvProducts: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var productAdapter: ProductAdapter


    // ViewModel
    private val productListViewModel: ProductListViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        _binding = FragmentProductListBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        // Product Type
        rvProductTypes = binding.rvProductCategory
        rvProductTypes.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)

        productTypeAdapter = ProductCategoryAdapter()
        rvProductTypes.adapter = productTypeAdapter

        // Asignar el listener al adapter
        productTypeAdapter.setItemClickListener(this)

        productListViewModel.getProductTypeList().observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { productTypeList ->
            productTypeAdapter.productTypeList = productTypeList
            productTypeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

        // Products
        rvProducts = binding.rvProducts
        rvProducts.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)

        productAdapter = ProductAdapter()
        rvProducts.adapter = productAdapter

        // Asignar el listener al adapter
        productAdapter.setItemClickListener(this)

        productListViewModel.getProductList().observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { productList ->
            productAdapter.productList = productList
            productAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

        // Filter
        binding?.ivFilterProducts?.setOnClickListener { view ->
            // Código del evento onClick del botón
            val popup = PopupMenu(requireContext(), view)
            popup.inflate(R.menu.menu_product_sort)
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener { item ->
                when (item.itemId) {
                    R.id.sort_asc -> {
                        sortProducts(SortOrder.ASC)
                        true
                    }
                    R.id.sort_desc -> {
                        sortProducts(SortOrder.DESC)
                        true
                    }
                    else -> false
                }
            }
            popup.show()
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sorts the product list by name in the specified order and updates the adapter.
     * @param sortOrder The order in which to sort the products.
     */
    private fun sortProducts(sortOrder: SortOrder) {
        val sortedProductList = when (sortOrder) {
            SortOrder.ASC -> productListViewModel.getProductList().value?.sortByNameAsc()
            SortOrder.DESC -> productListViewModel.getProductList().value?.sortByNameDesc()
        }
        sortedProductList?.let {
            productAdapter.productList = it
            productAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }

    // Declara el TAG en la parte superior de tu clase
    private val TAG = "onProductTypeItemClick"
    private var beforePosition = RecyclerView.NO_POSITION
    private var afterPosition = RecyclerView.NO_POSITION

    /**
     * Este método se llama cuando se hace clic en un ProductType en el RecyclerView.
     * Muestra un Toast con el nombre y la edad del usuario.
     */
    override fun onProductTypeItemClick(productType: ProductType) {
        // Crear el mensaje a mostrar en el Toast
        val message = "Nombre: ${productType.name}"

        // Mostrar un Toast con el mensaje
        Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        // Obtener la posición del registro seleccionado
        val position = productTypeAdapter.productTypeList.indexOf(productType)

        // Mostrar la posición en el Logcat
        Log.d(TAG, "XXXXXbeforePosition: $beforePosition")
        Log.d(TAG, "XXXXXPosition: $position")

        // Pintar el background de la posición seleccionada
        // 1. Obtener la vista de la tarjeta seleccionada
        val selectedViewHolder = rvProductTypes.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position)
        // 2. Obtener la vista de la tarjeta a modificar
        val selectedView = selectedViewHolder?.itemView?.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.cl_product_background)
        // 3. Obtener la vista de la tarjeta anteriormente seleccionada
        val beforeViewHolder = rvProductTypes.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(beforePosition)
        val beforeView = beforeViewHolder?.itemView?.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.cl_product_background)

        // Cambiar el fondo de la tarjeta seleccionada
        selectedView?.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected_item_background)

        // Reestablecer el fondo de la tarjeta anteriormente seleccionada
        beforeView?.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.default_item_background)

        // Actualizar el valor de la posición anterior
        beforePosition = position
    }

    override fun onProductTypeIdItemClick(productTypeId: String) {
        Log.e("onProductTypeItemClick", "START onProductTypeIdItemClick_____________________________________________________________")
        Log.e("onProductTypeItemClick", "roductTypeId: $productTypeId")
        Toast.makeText(context, "productTypeId: $productTypeId", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        rvProducts.adapter = productAdapter // deberías actualizar el adaptador de productos en lugar del de tipos de producto

        productListViewModel.getProductsByCategory(productTypeId).observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { productList ->
            productAdapter.productList = productList
            productAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        })

        Log.e(TAG, "rvProductTypes: ${rvProductTypes}")
        Log.e(TAG, "size: ${rvProductTypes.size}")
        Log.e("onProductTypeItemClick", "END onProductTypeIdItemClick_____________________________________________________________")
    }

    /**
     * Product
     * */
    override fun onProductItemClick(product: Product) {
        // Crear el mensaje a mostrar en el Toast
        val message = "Nombre: ${product.name}"

        // Mostrar un Toast con el mensaje
        Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        Log.e("onProductItemClick", "product ${product} ")  // id=null, name=Producto xxx1, description=Descripción del Producto 1, price=10.0, available=true, type=0001
    }

    override fun onProductIdItemClick(productId: String) {
        Log.e("onProductIdItemClick", "productId: $productId")
        Toast.makeText(context, "Producto Id: $productId", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

}
```

```
class ProductListViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val productRepository = ProductRepository()
    // Products
    private val productList: LiveData<List<Product>> = productRepository.getProductList()
    // Types
    private val productTypeList: LiveData<List<ProductType>> = productRepository.getProductTypeList()

    fun getProductList(): LiveData<List<Product>> {
        return productList
    }
    fun getProductTypeList(): LiveData<List<ProductType>> {
        return productTypeList
    }

    fun getProductsByCategory(category: String): LiveData<List<Product>> {
        return productRepository.getProductsByCategory(category)
    }

}
```

conservación de registros en RecyclerView al rotar la pantalla Kotlin fragment.

Comment: can you please, also, show your repository?